# Change colors for NA values to gray in R plotly scatter 3d

Tags: r, plotly, scatter3d

I'm trying to generate a plot in which I want to show NA values in translucent gray, and a set of numeric values I want to plot with a blue-red color scale. By default, plotly colors my NAs with a dark gray solid color, but I figure there must be a way to change that somehow. Is there anyway to do it? Here is a mockup of my code:

```
library("plotly")

blue_red <- rev(c("#A50026", "#D73027", "#F46443", "#FDAE61", "#FEE090"
                , "#E0F3F8", "#ABD9E9", "#74ADD1", "#4575B4", "#313695"))

mtcars$brand <- sapply(strsplit(rownames(mtcars), " "), "[[", 1)
mtcars[mtcars$brand=="Merc","mpg"] <- NA

fig <- plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~wt, y = ~hp, z = ~qsec, 
        marker = list(size = 6),
        color=~mpg,
        colors = blue_red,
        type = "scatter3d", 
        mode = "markers")
fig
```

[image]

I found a somewhat similar question here: https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-change-colors-for-na-values-to-gray-in-a-choropleth-map/15746/3 but I haven't been able to translate that to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited to make sense**  OK, so you have known triplets for x,y,z coordinates and you want to assign colors to various values of `mpg`.  Can you simply do the following?

`mtcars[mtcars$brand=="Merc","mpg"] <- your_chosen_value`  and assign a desired color to that value.

If that distorts the colors mapped to numeric values that are genuine, maybe it's simpler to plot all the non-"Merc" data with one call and then plot all the "Merc" data with a second call that uses a simple, single-value color assignment instead of your `blue_red` vector.